# Permissions issue when trying to create a database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

- I am on a MacBook Air 2017 version Mojave latest update.
- Used Homebrew
- Downloaded MariaDB and MySql

I am a newbie and trying to do the work provided. When trying to create a database called test, I get this error:

ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './test' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

I've tried:

CREATE DATABASE test;

I have also tried:

mysqladmin -u root -p create test

MySQL [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE test;
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './test' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
MySQL [(none)]> mysqladmin -u root -p create test
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqladmin -u root -p create test' at line 1
MySQL [(none)]>

It seems to be saying permissions denied. I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Try with root user name and root password.

Comment: Hello thanks. I use mysql -u root -p 

But after I type CREATE DATABASE test

the error message still pops up

Comment: What were you logged in as you _installed_ mysql/mariadb?  The error implies that mysql/mariadb does not have permissions to get at its own directories.

Answer (score 0):

There is a permission issue. To overcome that you need to give GRANT to that user.

Follow this steps:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114844

Comment: I am still having issues. I am unsure how to explain them as I would need live help. :(

I am the root user

Comment: Try to create a user with root user. Then assign grant via root user. Then login with new user and then try to create a new database.

Comment: I don't know how to do any of this. I am just learning today. I am so confused now.

Comment: @Temicka First of all welcome to mysql. Just search my steps and follow the query.